# phpexcel Arrange the data inside php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpexcel, calc

Code:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/valesilveira.php'); ?>
<?php 
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
}

$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

switch ($theType) {
case "text":
$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
break;    
case "long":
case "int":
$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
break;
case "double":
$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
break;
case "date":
$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
break;
case "defined":
$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
break;
}
return $theValue;
}
}

$colname_dados = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['id_proposta'])) {
$colname_dados = $_GET['id_proposta'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_valesilveira, $valesilveira);
$query_dados = sprintf("SELECT posicao, dados.desc, quantidade, unitario FROM propostas, clientes, dados WHERE propostas.id_proposta = dados.id_proposta AND propostas.id_cliente = clientes.id_cliente AND propostas.id_proposta = %s ORDER BY posicao ASC", GetSQLValueString($colname_dados, "int"));
$dados = mysql_query($query_dados, $valesilveira) or die(mysql_error());
$row_dados = mysql_fetch_assoc($dados);
$totalRows_dados = mysql_num_rows($dados);

$colname_propostas = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['id_proposta'])) {
$colname_propostas = $_GET['id_proposta'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_valesilveira, $valesilveira);
$query_propostas = sprintf("SELECT id_proposta, data FROM propostas WHERE id_proposta = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_propostas, "int"));
$propostas = mysql_query($query_propostas, $valesilveira) or die(mysql_error());
$row_propostas = mysql_fetch_assoc($propostas);
$totalRows_propostas = mysql_num_rows($propostas);

$data = $row_propostas['data'];
setlocale (LC_ALL, "pt_BR", "ptb");
$data_formatada = strftime("%d de %B de %Y", strtotime($data));
?>
<?php


// require the PHPExcel file 
require 'Classes/PHPExcel.php'; 

// simple query 

$headings = array('posicao','desc','quantidade','unitario','iliquido','total');

if ($result = mysql_query($query_dados) or die(mysql_error())) { 
    // Create a new PHPExcel object 
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel(); 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('List of Data'); 

    $rowNumber = 1; 
    $col = 'A'; 
    foreach($headings as $heading) { 
       $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$heading); 
       $col++; 
    } 

    // Loop through the result set 
    $rowNumber = 2; 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) { 
       $col = 'A'; 
       foreach($row as $cell) { 
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$cell); 
          $col++; 
       } 
       $rowNumber++; 
    } 


    // Freeze pane so that the heading line won't scroll 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->freezePane('A2'); 

    // Save as an Excel BIFF (xls) file 
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5'); 

   header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); 
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="userList.xls"'); 
   header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); 

   $objWriter->save('php://output'); 
   exit(); 
} 
echo 'a problem has occurred... no data retrieved from the database'; 
?>
<?php
mysql_free_result($dados);

mysql_free_result($propostas);

mysql_free_result($data);
?>
```

Ok the code i have done so far, but this only gets data from database and loops it and i would like for the last 2 cols make some arrangements.

I get data for the posicao, desc, quantidade, unitario, but for the iliquido and total i would like to make some calcs.

For iliquido i would like to make the unitario*quantidade and show all the results on the column.

And for the total i would like to make a single row with the total of the iliquido values like =sum(2ndrow:lastrow).

Answer (score 0):

You can just insert as value of a PHPExcel cell the formulas which will behave as common Excel formulas. So just put:

```
=A$row*C$row
```

in the column you prefer to get the unitario*quantidade result for that row. The same for the sum.

For instance, while you are doing this loop:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) { 
   $col = 'A'; 
   foreach($row as $cell) { 
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$cell); 
      $col++; 
   } 
   //add this line to get the unitario*quantidade result
   //in the last column
   //here I'm assuming that quantitade and unitario are placed
   //in column A and C in your excel, but this may be wrong, so
   //replace them with the proper values
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,"=A$row*C$row");
   $rowNumber++; 
}
```

Comment: where do i put that? first time using phpexcel for a work im doing, could you please write that code on my main code and paste it all here so i can see how to do it.

Comment: oh it worked it makes the c*d but now how could i make the sum of all the values of iliquido the results that was made from early? in a separate line.

Comment: You just need to do the same thing: you put the Excel formula as a value of the cell you desire. I think you may use the sum function...